# Does Google Sheets allow moving a chart to its own sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I know that Google Sheets used to allow moving a chart to its own worksheet so that nothing else is in that sheet. All the instructions I've found for how to do so are no longer relevant to the most recent UI.

Can this still be done? How?

Comment: you mean to move it after its created?

Comment: Yes, after it's created.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- select the chart
- click on three dots
- select either **Copy chart** or **Move to own sheet**

  [image: 0]

Answer (score 2):

I just discovered how to do it. Click the triple-dot menu in the upper-right corner of the chart, and click "Move to own sheet". Somehow I missed it in there before, or didn't look!